# Does the A press to "X is attacking Y" need to be on-beat to initiate a combo attack?

Tags: mother-3

When you attack an enemy, you get a message box that announces your attack. You can dismiss it with A. You can then combo an enemy by tapping A to the heartbeat of said enemy.

I've noticed that the combo difficulty increases exponentially the higher their "heart frequency" is. Even with massive abuse of save states and a 5× emulator slowdown, I can't manage to combo (say) a Clayman more than twice, and even that second combo is more of an accident than something I can rely upon in normal gameplay. I guess this means that I must be doing something inherently wrong.

Now, yes, the first few beats are harder than the following ones; when you do have a few notes on screen, their visual movement also help you keep the combo going. However, this seems *really* hard. I must be doing something consistently wrong, or maybe you're just not meant to 16-combo all enemies, even if you're willing to save and restore state as many times as needed. I don't know, but I figure that it should be easier to get a 2-combo properly than through a turbo controller.

So, here's what I could be doing wrong: does the first A *also* need to be in beat to count? do I instead want it instead to be off-beat so I have the time to press A on the right beat?

Comment: Disabling frame skip is marginally helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it's apparently just really difficult to do this on an emulator for internal timing reasons.  (I played the entire game through without ever bothering with combos ever at all, for what it's worth - they're not even remotely necessary)

Comment: @shinrai Actually I've found they helped me immensely, at least in Chapter 2. A 16-combo usually nets you more than twice your regular damage.

Comment: I don't deny that they're helpful, but the game is not so difficult as to *require* them was my point.  Sound desync issues are just sort of a fact of life in emulators though :(

Answer (score 4):

Kinda. After completing the game and trying to combo as much as possible (to the point of saving a state before every single attack and loading it back if I didn't get enough combo) I think I have the right mental model for how it works.

Basically, the answer is two-fold:

- Technically, **no**.
- Practically, **yes**. Kinda.

I'm going to show a rough timeline like so:

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
```

This line shows the "hidden heartbeat" of a generic enemy, with a little bit of tolerance to the sides. If we add to the timeline a track showing when you'd press A, this is what would happen in an ideal world: you'd get each beat exactly right.

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
A: ----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A----
```

...but even if you were slightly off, the game would still accept it:

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
A: ----A----A-------A----A----A------A------A-----A----A-----A------A----A----
```

However if you miss a `(♫)` entirely, your combo is over and control goes over to the next character. I'll show combo-ending A presses with a `×`.

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
A: ----A------A----A--×--- 3 hit combo
A: ----A----A----×------×- 2 hit combo
```

Now, what you would do in practice is get the "Lucas attacks!" prompt, start tapping with the beat on the controller off-button, then start pressing A away. The question is about that first A press.

The game does not check if that A press is on beat, or else you wouldn't be able to get combos going accidentally with a turbo controller:

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
A: -------A-A-×-×-×-×-×---  accidental 2 hit combo!
```

This actually happens fairly frequently (of course, the faster the tempo is the better) and, on some of the harder songs, it's probably the most reliable way to get a little extra damage through. Given the way the rolling health counter works, this also means you might be able to avoid taking a little damage.

However, long combos are typically worth it. While diminishing returns are in place, a 16 hit combo can normally deal about 2.5× as much damage as a single attack. (Finally, if you're a dirty scumbag save-state cheater like me, you can use the length of the combo to affect the RNG and enemy attack patterns or successful use of items or techniques. This can be handy on the tougher battles!)

So, as I have said these two series of A presses are just as good:

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
A: ----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A----
A: --------A-A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A-----A----
```

...but if you are a human being, rather than a tool assisted speed runner, you'll have a far easier time nailing the first line of beats. In other words, if you start your sequence of beats off, you'll have quite the hard time adjusting it going forward.

So, **yes, you *do* want that first press to be on-beat, even though it needn't be.**

The devil here, however, is in the detail. If you're slightly early with your first A press, you basically won't be able to combo at all!

```
♫: ---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---(♫)---
A: --A-------×-----×-----×-----×-----×-----×-----×-----×-----×-----×-----×----
```

No matter how on time you would've been with each beat on the line, you accidentally missed the beat right after the prompt and suddenly you can't combo any more. This is not a good place to be and, if you're not cheating with save states, you probably need to try and stop for a moment and listen to the tune so you can readjust your timing  before attempting another combo. Putting the enemy to sleep, as always, helps.

---

Finally, if the whole combo system bores you to death and you still want to deal awesome damage to your enemy, the ever so helpful [starmen.net](http://forum.starmen.net/forum/Games/Mother3/Full-Cheat-Code-List) has the *Gameshark v1* cheat code just for you.

```
A986DFE1 8532B3F6
7750E1A0 3FACA8E8
368FBAB5 4691351A
```

With this cheat code, you will simply need to press A 17 times every time one of your characters attacks. A turbo controller is advised for maximum cheatinghood.